# SwiftUI - How to get daily total accumulated Amount using CoreData

Tags: swiftui, core-data, swiftui-list

I have issue with updating daily accumulated  balances correctly when using @SectionedFetchRequest and sectionIdentifier: .month .

For example following is the list of daily transactions

```
| Date               | Amount  |Index  |   
| --------           | ------- |-------|
|   June , 30, 2023  | +5      |    0  |
|   June , 30, 2023  | -10     |    1  |  
|   June , 28, 2023  | -4      |    2  |  
|   May  , 17, 2023  | +15     |    0  |  
|   May  , 09, 2023  | -2      |    1  |  
|   April, 19, 2023  | -4      |    0  |
|   April, 12, 2023  | +5      |    1  |
```

When using the following code

```
    struct TransactionsDetail: View {

    @SectionedFetchRequest<String, TransactionEntity>(sectionIdentifier: \.month,    sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.transactionDate, order: .reverse)]) private var  transactionGroupByMonth

    }
```

```
    var body: some View {

       List {
           ForEach(Array(transactionGroupByMonth.enumerated()), id: \.offset) {   (index, monthDate) in
              Section {
                  ForEach(monthDate) { item in
                      HStack{
                          HStack {
                              Text(item.transactionDate, style: .date)
                              Spacer()
                              Text("\(String(format: "%.2f",item.transactionAmount))")  
                                    
                              Text("\(String(format: "%.2f",transactionGroupByMonth[index].reduce(0) {$0 + $1.transactionAmount}))")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } header: {
                        Text(monthDate.id)
                    }
                    
                }
                
                .padding(.vertical, 1)
            }
  }
```

The accumulated amount is being displayed as follow:

```
| Date               | Amount  | Accumulated Amount |
| --------           | ------- | --------------     |
|   June , 30, 2023  | +5      | -9                 |
|   June , 30, 2023  | -10     | -9                 |            
|   June , 28, 2023  | -4      | -9                 |
|   May  , 17, 2023  | +15     | +13                |
|   May  , 09, 2023  | -2      | +13                |
|   April, 19, 2023  | -4      | +1                 |
|   April, 12, 2023  | +5      | +1                 |
```

However I would like the accumulated daily amount to be auto updated as follow when any transaction is added or deleted.

```
| Date               | Amount  | Accumulated Amount |
| --------           | ------- | --------------     |
|   June , 30, 2023  | +5      | +5                 |
|   June , 30, 2023  | -10     | 0                  |            
|   June , 28, 2023  | -4      | +10                |
|   May  , 17, 2023  | +15     | +14                |
|   May  , 09, 2023  | -2      | -1                 |
|   April, 19, 2023  | -4      | +1                 |
|   April, 12, 2023  | +5      | +5                 |
```

Appreciate your help? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to change the format of the table or the numbers?

Comment: Hi @ koen. Just numbers. I I would like the accumulated daily amount to be updated as and when any transaction is added or deleted. Thanks

Comment: You can’t use reduce and calculate the sum for a month on _each_ row. You need to filter the array so you only sum values up to the date for the current row. This sounds a bit complicated so maybe it’s best to do separately beforehand

Comment: Hi @Joakim Danielson. Could you please help and let me know how to filter the array  sum values up to the date for the current row. I tried filtering by date but couldn't get the accumulated daily amount. Thanks

Comment: I don't have  a good idea how to do that inside a ForEach in a view, I would look into doing this separately outside the view but then you can't use a SectionedFetchRequest

Comment: Hi Joakim Danielson. I found that the index number for the rows which are grouped by the month is defaulted back to zero. I have added the index number for each row in my question for the reference. Is it possible to update the index number for each row so it can be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 and so on . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an attribute to the model to store the accumulated daily amount when any transaction is added or deleted.

The View should just fetch what needs to be displayed without any calculations.

Comment: Hi @ malhal. I would like to display the accumulated amount at each index. How can I filter the array sum values up to the date for the current row. Thanks

Comment: Hi @ malhal.I tried adding new attribute for the accumulated amount. However when I delete old transaction amount the accumulated amount doesn’t get adjusted.

Comment: Call the same func that updates accumulated amount from your delete transaction func

Comment: Hi malhal. Just to clarify the accumulated amount is getting saved in core Data as and when I entered a new transaction. I am not sure whether can update already saved accumulating amount.